# Why the requested decimal precision is actually one less if the result is greater than 1?

Tags: python, decimal

up until now I never had to deal with decimals. However, as mentioned in the title, I observe something that I do not get... consider this :

```
>>> import decimal as dec
>>> D = dec.Decimal
>>> def precision(prec):
    return dec.Context(prec = prec)

>>> with dec.localcontext(precision(2)):
    D(1)/7


Decimal('0.14')
>>> with dec.localcontext(precision(2)):
    D(12)/7


Decimal('1.7')
>>> with dec.localcontext(precision(4)):
    D(1)/7


Decimal('0.1429')
>>> with dec.localcontext(precision(4)):
    D(12)/7


Decimal('1.714')
```

Why is it that when the result is > 1, the given number of digits after the floating point is one lower than what requested ?

Comment: 1.714 is four significant figures. The 1 at the start counts.

Comment: Damn, that... sucks... that was not the feeling I got from reading the docs, should have red more carefully I guess... Thanks man